# How to make getusermedia capture based on video constraint in Firefox? In Chrome everything is according to the code, but not in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, html5-video, getusermedia

I have a problem when I want to capture image from getusermedia, the captured image in Firefox is not retaining the ratio I have set in video constraint.
this is the ratio for getting the video, but from what I've seen the video not taking the constraints in Firefox

```
if(navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
        if(window.innerWidth >= 600){
          this.canvasWidth = 480;
          this.canvasHeight = 360;
        } else {
          this.canvasWidth = 240;
          this.canvasHeight = 240;
        }
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: false,video: {facingMode: 'user', width: this.canvasWidth * 2, height: this.canvasHeight * 2} }).then(stream => {
            this.useWebcam = true;
            this.canvas.nativeElement.style.display = 'none';
            this.video.nativeElement.srcObject = stream;
            this.stream = stream;
            this.ref.detectChanges();
            this.video.nativeElement.play();
            console.log(stream);
        }).catch(reason => {
          this.useWebcam = false;
          if(this.acceptable){
            this.acceptable = false;
            this.eMessage = reason + "<br/>Please check your camera to continue.";
            this.ref.detectChanges();
          }
          // alert(reason + " \nPlease check your camera to continue.")
        });
      } else {
        this.eMessage = "Please check your camera to continue.";
      }
```

And this is for taking the picture and retaking the picture

```
capture() {
    this.canvas.nativeElement.style.display = 'block';
    this.canvas.nativeElement.getContext("2d").scale(-1,1);
    this.canvas.nativeElement.getContext("2d").drawImage(this.video.nativeElement, 0, 0, this.canvas.nativeElement.width * 2, this.canvas.nativeElement.height * 2, 0, 0, -1 * this.canvas.nativeElement.width, this.canvas.nativeElement.height);
    this.canvas.nativeElement.getContext("2d").restore();
    this.captured = this.canvas.nativeElement.toDataURL("image/png");
    this.video.nativeElement.style.display = 'none';
  }

  retake() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.canvas.nativeElement.getContext("2d").scale(-1,1);
      this.canvas.nativeElement.getContext("2d").clearRect(0, 0, -1 * this.canvas.nativeElement.width, this.canvas.nativeElement.height);
      this.canvas.nativeElement.getContext("2d").restore();
      this.canvas.nativeElement.style.display = 'none';
      this.video.nativeElement.style.display = 'block';
      this.captured = null;
    }, 20);
  }
```

How to make the video using the constraint given? This code worked in Chrome, not in Firefox? Thank you

Note:
I already read other questions before asking but still have no answer for my case. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after experimenting with my codes I can do the preview

```
positioningVideo(){
    //Check Orientation
    if(this.videoWidth > this.videoHeight){
      let temp = this.videoWidth;
      this.videoWidth = this.videoHeight;
      this.videoHeight = temp;
    }

    if(this.videoWidth > (this.canvasWidth * 2)){
      this.video.nativeElement.style.maxHeight = '' + this.canvasHeight + 'px' ;
      this.video.nativeElement.style.maxWidth = '' + (this.videoWidth / 2) + 'px';
    } else if(this.videoHeight > (this.canvasHeight * 2)){
      this.video.nativeElement.style.maxWidth = '' + this.canvasWidth + 'px' ;
      this.video.nativeElement.style.maxHeight = '' + (this.videoHeight / 2) + 'px';
    } else if(this.videoWidth == (this.canvasWidth * 2) && this.videoHeight == (this.canvasHeight * 2)){
      this.video.nativeElement.style.maxHeight = '' + this.canvasHeight + 'px' ;
      this.video.nativeElement.style.maxWidth = '' + this.canvasWidth + 'px' ;
    }

  }
```

and I used some calculation to set my starting coordinate

Note: I am using crop center so I calculate the margin top or left.

```
capture() {
    let coorX = 0, coorY = 0;
    
    if(this.videoWidth != (this.canvasWidth * 2)){
      coorX = (this.videoWidth - (this.canvasWidth * 2)) / 2;
    }
    if(this.videoHeight != (this.canvasHeight * 2)){
      coorY = (this.videoHeight - (this.canvasHeight * 2)) / 2;
    }
    this.canvas.nativeElement.style.display = 'block';
    this.canvas.nativeElement.getContext("2d").scale(-1,1);
    this.canvas.nativeElement.getContext("2d").drawImage(this.video.nativeElement, coorX, coorY, this.canvasWidth * 2, this.canvasHeight * 2, 0, 0, -1 * this.canvasWidth, this.canvasHeight);
    this.canvas.nativeElement.getContext("2d").restore();
    this.captured = this.canvas.nativeElement.toDataURL("image/png");
    this.video.nativeElement.parentElement.style.display = 'none';
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The constraints you present to getUserMedia() are requests. You won't always get the exact dimensions you request.

I agree with your observation that Google Chrome adheres to the dimensions you request more exactly than Firefox. I tried forcing Firefox to use exact dimensions using the `exact` attribute, but it refused with a constraint violation error.

I had to clip the captured Firefox image to make it the same size as the one I captured in Chrome. To make this look right to the user doing the capturing I also arranged, with some CSS, to clip the preview window.